# Weird display issue with vuetify in laravel. v-text-field gets an outline on focus

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuetify.js

So the problem is… when I focus on the v-text-field, I get an outline which is not desired.
And it's only happening in Laravel. When using plain Vue, the problem is not there.

In Laravel + Vuetify Project (See the blue outline? I don't want it there)
[image: In Laravel Project]

In Vue Project (Desired)
[image: In Vue Project]

I'm not sure as to why this is happening.
Also, this is the first time I'm trying Vuetify with Laravel

The code for both is the same, as below

```
<v-text-field
  label="Email"
  name="email"
  prepend-icon="mdi-email"
  type="email"
  :color="$store.state.sf_brandColor"
  v-model="login.email"
  @blur="$v.login.email.$touch()"
  :error-messages="login_emailErrors"
/>
<v-text-field
   label="Password"
   name="pass"
   prepend-icon="mdi-lock"
   type="password"
   :color="$store.state.sf_brandColor"
   v-model="login.password"
   @blur="$v.login.password.$touch()"
   :error-messages="login_passwordErrors"
/>
```

I've tried

```
input:focus {
  outline:none;
}
input:focus {
  border:none;
}
```

but it hasn't worked

In the developer tools, I checked the `<input>` tag. It doesn't have any border on focus.

[image: Dev Tools]

Please help, I can't think of more ways to even debug this.

Running

- Laravel 8.27.0
- Vue 2.5.17
- Vuetify 2.4.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... so just gave a though that maybe something might be interfering with vuetify, so removed tailwind CSS (comes default with Jetstream) as I dont use it.

And its fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

In your resources/sass/app.scss, delete `@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap"`

Run `npm run watch`

Done